# Error in if function

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I have run a long script to decide which model i should use to forecast. After doing accuracy tests on the in and out samples of the data i created a large `if` function to find which model is best the results of this would either be "ARIMA", "Arima.wgt", "AddHW", "MultHW", "AddHWwgt" and "MultHWwgt". During the script i have got the forecasts from each of these models and i want to use the `if` function to view them currently i have written

```
if(maxmod<-"ARIMA")
  modelf<-ArimaALTfa else
    if(maxmod<-"Arima.wgt")
      modelf<-ArimaALTfb else
        if(maxmod<-"AddHW")
          modelf<-HWAbfc else
            if(maxmod<-"MultHW")
              modelf<-HWMbfd else
                if(maxmod<-"AddHWwgt")
                  modelf<-HWAALTfe else
                    modelf<-HWMALTff
```

but i keep getting the error

```
Error in if (maxmod <- "ARIMA") modelf <- ArimaALTfa else if (maxmod <- "Arima.wgt") modelf <- ArimaALTfb else if (maxmod <- "AddHW") modelf <- HWAbfc else if (maxmod <- "MultHW") modelf <- HWMbfd else if (maxmod <- "AddHWwgt") modelf <- HWAALTfe else modelf <- HWMALTff : 
  argument is not interpretable as logical
```

This has happened for many different things i have tried eg instead of `modelf<-""` i tried `View("",title="")` and `modelf<-View("",title="")` but still it saya it isn't logical... is there an error in the way i have written it or is there another problem?

Extra detail and code available if needed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really need the [`switch`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/switch) function.

```
modelf <- switch(
  maxmod,
  ARIMA     = ArimaALTfa,
  Arima.wgt = ArimaALTfb,
  AddHW     = HWAbfc,
  MultHW    = HWMbfd,
  AddHWwgt  = HWAALTfe,
  HWMALTff
)
```

---

Your specific problem was trying to *assign* values to `maxmod` instead of *comparing for equality*. Although the `switch` statement is preferable, try replacing

```
if(maxmod<-"ARIMA")
```

with

```
if(maxmod == "ARIMA")
```

`maxmod == "ARIMA"` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` (a logical value).

`maxmod<-"ARIMA"` assigns the value `"ARIMA"` to a variable named `maxmod` (and invisibly returns that string).

Comment: is this instead of the if function?

Comment: nevermind. it works thank you so much! i never knew this function existed!!

Comment: oh yes of course!! i completely missed the `==` thankyou for your help